# Verify signature by Bouncy Castle with Java

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle

By using OpenSsl, I generated cert "test.cer" and keystor "test.p12"

Then the Sertificate created:

```
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");

    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certFactory
            .generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("test.cer"));
```

Read source file and generated Private key:

```
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(new File("source.txt").toPath());
        char[] keystorePassword = "password".toCharArray();
        char[] keyPassword = "password".toCharArray();
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("test.p12"), keystorePassword);
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey("archive", keyPassword);
```

And sign:

```
    byte[] signedMessage = null;
    List<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
    CMSTypedData cmsData = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data);
    certList.add(signingCertificate);
    Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
    CMSSignedDataGenerator cmsGenerator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
    ContentSigner contentSigner
            = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").build(signingKey);
    cmsGenerator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
            new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC")
                    .build()).build(contentSigner, signingCertificate));
    cmsGenerator.addCertificates(certs);
    CMSSignedData cms = cmsGenerator.generate(cmsData, true);
    byte[] signedMessage = cms.getEncoded();
```

signedMessage I write to file with extension .p7s :

```
    File targetFile = new File(Paths.get(fileDir).getParent().toString(), "/" + "signed.p7s");
    targetFile.createNewFile();
    Files.write(Paths.get(targetFile.getAbsolutePath()), signedMessage);
```

And then, when I'm trying to verify signature I receive false-result. This is how verification realised:

```
   byte[] signedData = Files.readAllBytes(new File("signed.p7s").toPath());
    ByteArrayInputStream bIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(signedData);
    ASN1InputStream aIn = new ASN1InputStream(bIn);
    CMSSignedData s = new CMSSignedData(ContentInfo.getInstance(aIn.readObject()));
    aIn.close();
    bIn.close();
    Store certs = s.getCertificates();
    SignerInformationStore signers = s.getSignerInfos();
    Collection<SignerInformation> c = signers.getSigners();
    SignerInformation signer = c.iterator().next();
    Collection<X509CertificateHolder> certCollection = certs.getMatches(signer.getSID());
    Iterator<X509CertificateHolder> certIt = certCollection.iterator();
    X509CertificateHolder certHolder = certIt.next();
    boolean verifResult = signer.verify(newJcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().build(certHolder));
```

In {JAVA_HOME}/lib/security  I preliminarily extract local_policy.jar

I don't understand, why Signature is not verified. Why signer.verify(newJcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().build(certHolder)) returns false

Comment: What is your question? also: why do you access the file with two different paths? `new File(Paths.get(fileDir).getParent().toString(), "/" + "signed.p7s")` vs. `new File("signed.p7s")` Is the signed file closed, before you try to read it again?

Comment: 1. I don't understand, why Signature is not verified. Why signer.verify(newJcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().build(certHolder)) returns false.  2.First part of path is the absolute path (home/data/), second - part is the name of file

Comment: **Unable to reproduce.** If I stitch together the pieces of code you posted, with variable names changed as needed and filenames/paths suitable for my system, verify=true as expected. FYI you don't need to read and parse the cert separately, it's in the p12. (Also .p7s is registered for _detached_ signature, not encapsulated, but that doesn't matter to this code; it _might_ confuse _other_ tools.)

Comment: I understand the difference between path and filename, but for signing you use an absolute path and for verifying the signature you use a relative path, that could lead to the problem that you don't verify the file that you created on signing. Also please add your question to the main text or the heading, not just leave it in the comments ;)

Comment: The problem was in cer-file. After recreation of test.cer the problem is gone